# How to make an object move only when the player is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m making a 3D puzzle game and I am trying to make a door(object) close gradually only when my player is moving. In other words, I want my door to close when my player is moving toward it and I want my door to open when my player is moving away from it. Haven’t been able to find any help online about this.

Comment: What is the specific problem that you try to solve? Are you able to execute any logic when the character moves? Are you able to determine distance from the door? And distance changes? There are many answerable aspects of your question, so you need to narrow down the problem-space. You might break your question up into separate questions that you may ask.

Comment: You’re right. Although the situation I’m in is quite tricky to explain but I’ll try my best to narrow it down to be more specific. I don’t want the door to close base on the position of the player. For exemple, I don’t want the door to close when my player is at “x” meters from it. I want the door to close when my player is moving toward it depending on which way my character is moving on an axis. For exemple, let’s say moving toward the door mean moving on the “+ z” axis and moving away from the door mean moving on the “- z” axis. I want the door to close/open when those traits are met.

Comment: Are you able to run some code that you write when the player changes his/her position?

Comment: Yes, now that I can detect when the player is moving toward the door/ away from the door, I need a way to close/open it smoothly. I tried using a rigidbody and adding force to it and it work, it’s just not the result that I’m looking for... is there an other way to make the movement of the door smooth?

Comment: Do you know how distance is to be measured between two points?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be: How do I detect if an object is moving towards another or further away.

->

```
// Wherever you get these from
public Transform door;
public Transform player;

private float lastDistance;

private void Start()
{
    // Store initial distance
    lastDistance = Vector3.Distance(door.position, player.position);
}

private void Update()
{
    // get current distance
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(door.position, player.position);

    if(distance < lastDistance)
    {
        // => Is moving towards door
    }
    else if(distance > lastDistance)
    {
        // is moving away from door
    }
    else
    {
        // distance stayed equal
    }

    lastDistance = distance;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what I’m looking for, thanks a lot!